# Can't get Google Calendar to populate FullCalendar

Tags: google-api, fullcalendar

I'm new to programming so please excuse the improper terminology, but I was able to get a basic FullCalendar added to my website and would like to populate the calendar based on one of my public Google Calendars. I followed the steps on FullCalendar's website for setting up Google Calendar  but I still just see a blank calendar, even though there are events on the public Google Calendar.  The only step I was unsure of when setting things up was the Authorized JavaScript Origins section of setting up the Google API.  I am using a GitHub pages site and it would not accept the full path name for my site so I just put the main hub portion (https://username.github.io) in this Authorized JavaScript Origins field. Is this incorrect?  What needs to go in this path if I am using the FullCalendar on a site with the following type of URL: https://stephmorgan.github.io/repository/ ?

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" />
    <script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
    <script src="fullcalendar/gcal.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        googleCalendarApiKey: "<API-KEY>",
        events: {
            googleCalendarId: "b3eki2m39g1lcfcq3nnl1vb9lo@group.calendar.google.com"
            className: "gcal-event" 
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="calendar"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: https://stephmorgan.github.io should be what you need to add, if that's the URL where the calendar is being shown. That's the domain. It doesn't care about the exact path. Just the correct domain is needed as the origin. If it still doesn't work then show your code here, and also report any error messages you get in the browser console / network tabs

Comment: Great, thanks.  Yes, that domain is correct for where the calendar is being shown and that's what I put for Authorized JavaScript Origins when I set up the API.  I don't see any events from the public google calendar though, just the blank fullCalendar.  No error messages in the console.  Below is the code:

Comment: can you add the code to the question please? Edit it here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45744044/edit. P.S. https://stephmorgan.github.io/ returns a 404. Are you sure that's the correct address?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="fullcalendar/gcal.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        })
    });

Comment: followed by this code (comment was too long when combined, is there a better way to post code on here?)$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
            googleCalendarApiKey: "200162627183-vnl2pm5q1pp1h7nj9hihrvsralr01bp9.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            events: {
                googleCalendarId: "Calendar ID: b3eki2m39g1lcfcq3nnl1vb9lo@group.calendar.google.com"
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

Comment: yes, edit the question, as i suggested above. Click the "edit" button at the bottom of the question, or click the link I gave in my comment.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  My first post...  I added the code to the question.  The website is actually at https://stephmorgan.github.io/PUMC_Lifegroup_married-w-pre-k-kids/

Comment: I think `googleCalendarId: "Calendar ID: b3eki2m39g1lcfcq3nnl1vb9lo@group.calendar.google.com"` should be `googleCalendarId: "b3eki2m39g1lcfcq3nnl1vb9lo@group.calendar.google.com"`, as per the example at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/. It thinks "Calendar ID: " is part of the ID, which obviously it isn't, and Google won't recognise it

Comment: Thank you for spotting this error.  I fixed that but still do not see any calendar events on the FullCalendar.  Are there any other steps that need to be performed before events will display on the embedded calendar?  Does the Authorized redirect URIs field need to be populated when setting up the Google API?  I have Authorized JavaScript origins field set to https://stephmorgan.github.io but have the Authorized redirect URIs field blank right now.

Comment: I've just looked in the Google API config for my own public calendars, and I don't see anything about Authorised JavaScript Origins. Are you sure you created the right kind of credentials? It should be an "API Key", not an "Oauth Client ID" or a "Service Account". I just have an option for "Key restriction", with choices "None", "HTTP Referrers", "IP Addresses", "Android Apps" or "iOS Apps".

Comment: You are right, I had the wrong type of credentials.  I believe the instructions on the fullCalendar site said to choose browser key and I didn't see that option and made a wrong guess.  The first time I fixed this the calendar still didn't populate any events, but I continued to look through my code and took the <> out of API key section and it works now!!  Thank you so much for your help.  I would have probably given up otherwise.  Much appreciated!

Comment: No problem. I have written all the bits up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems:

1) `googleCalendarId: "Calendar ID: b3eki2m39g1lcfcq3nnl1vb9lo@group.calendar.google.com"` should be `googleCalendarId: "b3eki2m39g1lcfcq3nnl1vb9lo@group.calendar.google.com"`, as per the example at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar. It thinks "Calendar ID: " is part of the ID, which obviously it isn't, and Google won't recognise it.

2) The same issue with the API Key - remove the `<` and `>` from the ends of the string.

3) It sounds like you chose the wrong kind of credentials - the API key config does not contain a section from JavaScript origins etc. You must choose to create an API Key (sometimes called a Browser Key), and *not* Oauth Client ID or Service Account.